# Efficiency: reuse Term Lucene 6

Tags: lucene, processing-efficiency, memory-efficient

I want to reuse the Term object instead of creating a new one every time I call this method:

```
public long getDF(String term) throws Exception {
    return indexReader.docFreq(new Term("content", term));
}
```

I read in the documentation that, I can use this constructor of Term to reuse it:

```
public Term(String fld)
Constructs a Term with the given field and empty text. This serves two purposes: 1) reuse of a Term with the same field. 2) pattern for a query.
```

However, I don't know what is the next step as there is no setters in the Term documentation nor reset() method.

Any hint on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Constructing Terms is cheap. You probably shouldn't worry too much about trying to reuse them. If you are seeing real performance issues, you should run a profiler. I'd guess constructing terms is not the real problem, and attempting to reuse clauses like this will just complicate things for no discernible benefit.

That said, you could reuse it by getting the Term's BytesRef from Term.bytes(), and directly modifying the underlying byte array.

```
String text = "text";
Term term = new Term("field");
BytesRef bytes = term.bytes();
bytes.bytes = new byte[UnicodeUtil.maxUTF8Length(text.length())];
bytes.length = UnicodeUtil.UTF16toUTF8(text, 0, text.length(), bytes.bytes);
```

Be careful that you aren't changing the value of a Term that is still in use. For instance, attempting to add two clauses to a BooleanQuery like this will, of course, not work.